# logstash with log4j socketappender doesn't work

Tags: log4j, logstash

I am trying to stream my logs through the log4j socket appender and trying to retrieve the same through the logstash log4j input plugin. My logstash configuration looks like

```
input {
        log4j
        {
         type=>"socketlogs"
          port=>"1995"
        }
}

output {
        stdout {}
        file
        { path=>"socket.log"}

}
```

My log4j.xml looks like below

```
<appender name="logstashsocketappender" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender">
        <param name="RemoteHost" value=<logstash ip>/>
        <param name="Port" value="1995"/>
        <param name="ReconnectionDelay" value="60000"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>   
    </appender>

<root>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="logstashsocketappender"/>
    </root>
```

I have a logger.info statement in the code for testing, however I do not see those in stdout in the logstash machine. These are the software versions I am using

logstash - 1.4.2
log4j - 1.7.5

Let me know if I am missing something here.

Thanks for the help
Gowri

Comment: Have you verified there isn't a firewall issue?  IE can your log4j machine reach port 1995 on your logstash machine?

Comment: Yes it does connect to the host and port.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use GELF? The log4j internals use TCP. GELF uses UDP, so it does not slow down your application.

**logstash.conf**

```
input {
    gelf {
        port => 12201
    }
}
```

**log4j.xml**

```
<appender name="gelf" class="biz.paluch.logging.gelf.log4j.GelfLogAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
    <param name="Host" value="udp:localhost" />
    <param name="Port" value="12201" />
</appender>
```

See https://github.com/mp911de/logstash-gelf for more docs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar issue using `logstash-1.4.2` and `log4j-1.2.17`: Only some of my logged messages arrive at logstash. If I log bunches of 10 messages only 5 to 10 messages arrive at logstash. The longer I post messages (in bunches) the more messages arrive. (after some iterations all 10 messages arrive) - Maybe there is an issue at startup where some messages are lost?

Maybe you try to log some messages too, to delimit the problem...

If it would be a misconfiguration, you would get `log4j:ERROR Could not connect to remote log4j server at [localhost]. We will try again later.` on `stderr` at the client side (sender).

It it seems to be a performance problem: If I wait 100ms between the messages of a bunch all messages arrive at logstash.